# Using Notepad++ Regex to format phone numbers

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I'm trying to format phone numbers in a large CSV directory. I will need to re-format this periodically as it changes so this is not a one-off solution. I have used Notepad++'s regex replace feature successfully in the past and would like to use this tool if possible. However, I'm open to better/faster methods including scripting like PowerShell, which I am familiar with.

**Sample of number formats in the database**:
XXX-XXXX
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
1XXXXXXXXXX
(XXX) XXX-XXXX
1(XXX) XXX-XXXX
(1XXX) XXX-XXXX
XXX-XXX-XXXX

That last one is what I want all phone numbers to look like in the final output. For the one that is lacking the area code, I would add a default value. For the ones with extra country codes, I would need to truncate it.

Here are some of the regex searches I've used:
FIND: `1-(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})`
REPLACE: \1-\2-\3
This works!

FIND: `1\((\d{3})\)\s(\d{3})-(\d{4})`
REPLACE: \1-\2-\3
This works!

FIND: `(\d{11})`
REPLACE: ???
This finds the correct string, but I don't know how to format the output.

FIND: `(\d{3})-(\d{4})`
REPLACE: XXX-\1-\2 (here the XXX is my standard area code that I will add)
This finds the correct substring in XXX-XXX-XXXX as well as XXX-XXXX and zip codes with +4 appended (XXXXX-XXXX). Need to just find the XXX-XXXX without anything preceding it and just from phone numbers. Because this is a CSV file, the actual character before each field is a comma.

My problem is twofold. 1) I don't know how to break up a found string into the parts I need for the replace. I need to convert blocks of digits (7, 10 and 11 digits) and format them to fit the pattern XXX-XXX-XXXX. 2) I don't know how to select just the string I'm searching for (i.e. only XXX-XXXX)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided you have a sample list of numbers like

```
Current             Expected
---------------------------------
123-1234            XXX-123-1234
1234567             XXX-123-4567
1234567890          123-456-7890
10123456789         012-345-6789
(123) 456-1234      123-456-1234
1(123) 123-1234     123-123-1234
1-123-123-1234      123-123-1234
(1999) 999-1234     999-999-1234
123-123-1234        123-123-1234
```

You may use

*Find What*: `^(?:1-?)?(?|\(1?(\d{3})\)|(\d{3}))[-\s]?(\d{3})[-\s]?(\d{4})$|^(\d{3})[-\s]?(\d{4})$`
*Replace With*: `(?1$1-$2-$3:XXX-$4-$5)`

[image]

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:1-?)?` - optional sequence of `1` and an optional `-`
- `(?|\(1?(\d{3})\)|(\d{3}))` - a branch reset group (syntax is `(?|...)`, all groups inside alternative branches receive same IDs) matching either:

  - `\(1?(\d{3})\)` - `(` + an optional `1` + Group 1 capturing 3 digits + `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `(\d{3})` -  Group 1 (still! because of a branch reset group) capturing 3 digits
- `[-\s]?` - 1 or 0 (optional) `-` or whitespace
- `(\d{3})` - Group 2 capturing 3 digits
- `[-\s]?` - an optional `-` or whitespace
- `(\d{4})` - Group 3 capturing 4 digits
- `$` - end of line
- `|` - OR
- `^` - start of line
- `(\d{3})` - Group 4 capturing 3 digits
- `[-\s]?` - an optional `-` or whitespace
- `(\d{4})` - Group 5 capturing 4 digits
- `$` - end of line

**The replacement pattern**:

- `(?1` - If Group 1 matched, then use

  - `$1-$2-$3` - Backreference to Group 1, 2 and 3 with hyphens in between
- `:` - or else
- `XXX-$4-$5` - `XXX` (or whatever the country code is), and Group 4 and 5 separated with a hyphen.
- `)` - end of the `if-then` block.

Comment: To change the format to `(123) 456-7890` use this replace string `(?1\($1\) $2-$3:XXX-$4-$5)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with powershell but yea it would be a good idea to make a small script to do this for you.

For the notepad approach though, i'd try running the replace twice:

1. **FIND**: `(?:^|,)(\d{3})[ -]?(\d{4})(?:,|$)`

   **REPLACE**: `XXX-\1-\2` where the XXX is your input area code
2. **FIND**: `\(?1?\(?(\d{3})\)?[ -]?(\d{3})[ -]?(\d{4})`

   **REPLACE**: `\1-\2-\3`

I don't think the order matters. Try it out in a test file first.

I'm not sure what you mean by your second question, are the regexes selecting numbers from the wrong column in csv? (if so that's another reason why a script would be better)